# Google Cloud Vision API from Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-vision

I've been accessing the Google Cloud Vision API from a script in a Google Sheet using UrlFetch and the REST API.

Until I got "UrlFetch failed because too much upload bandwidth was used" I didn't even know there was a quota on UrlFetch!

Is the a way to access Google Cloud APIs from a Google Apps Script so I can dodge the quota?

Answer (score 0):

Quotas protect the users of Google services by preventing unforeseen spikes in usage, on the benefit of both the user (who might get unexpected bills if the quota is related to a payed resource) and the community (who will have more resourcesa available, as they will not be monopolized by users that are making an excesive use of them).

That is the reason why quotas cannot be exceeded, although depending on the service (and specific quota) you are using, you may be able to request a quota increase by following the documented procedure or contacting the support team of the product in use.

Finally, in order to identify which is the quota that you are currently hitting, refer to this documentation page where you will be able to find the [quotas for URL Fetch](https://script.google.com/a/google.com/dashboard), which as of February 2018 are:

> [image]

As a side note, you have to take into account that these quotas are refreshed at the end of a 24-hour window, so your quota will be resetted to 0 every day. Moreover, this is also on a per-user basis, so you can work around this limitation by spreading your URLFetch usage across several users and days, if that is something that you can manage.